# What Is The Difference Between PresenceChannels and PrivateChannels - LARAVEL 5.8

Tags: laravel

I'm running `socket.io` with `laravel-echo-server` on my laravel app. And so I want to know the difference between `privateChannels` and `presenceChannels`. I feel that in alot of situations (if not all) they can be used interchangeably.

For example in my app:

- There are instances whereby I need to notify all users of a
  department.
- Then there are instances whereby I would need to notify some certain
  users with certain priviledges within a department.
- Then there could also be instances whereby I may need to give some
  users temporary access to some certain notifications etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/broadcasting#presence-channels):

> Presence channels build on the security of private channels while exposing the additional feature of awareness of who is subscribed to the channel. This makes it easy to build powerful, collaborative application features such as notifying users when another user is viewing the same page.

In other words, presence channels are itself also private channels but allow each user to *see* other users in the same channel. The commonly given example is a chat application with *rooms*, where each room is a channel.

For the scenarios described by you, I would expect that always a private channel is used. Your description reads like the application is protected by authentication, which automatically rules out *public channels*. As you also don't require your users to see who else received the notification (at least you didn't mention so), a presence channel doesn't make sense. This leaves us with the option of using a private channel.